How not to use docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1?
From quite some time I observed when building images I get an additional message:
#2 resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1

Which sometimes fail in my closed network environment:
#2 ERROR: failed to do request: Head "https://registry-.docker.io/v2/docker/dockerfile/manifests/1": EOF

After trying to search docker documentation, I see it is related to buildx https://docs.docker.com/build/buildkit/configure/ , but I do not understand how exactly.
How do I configure docker to use only our local nexus and do not make connections to docker.io?
